# Validating a new input that has been added by user using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css, validation

Within my project, I have validation on text boxes which highlights the border when clicked and then highlights red with an alert pop up if another area is clicked without any value being entered.

I also have a button that allows the user to add new input boxes themselves using jquery. I wondered if it is possible to make the these new inputs have the same validation with the highlighting of the border and pop up alert when they are added to the page using the button?

EDIT

```
     $(function() {
     $(".options").focus(function(){
          $(this).addClass("focused");
        });
        });

     $(function() {
        $(".options").blur(function(){
          $(this).removeClass("focused");
        });
        });

     $(function() {
     $(".options").focusout(function () {
         $(this).addClass("unfocused");
            if (!$(this).val()) {
                alert("Please ensure you have answered the question.");
            }
        });
        });

     $(function() {
            $(".options").blur(function(){
              $(this).removeClass("unfocused");
            });
            });
```

Apologies, above is the jquery code I've used for the already validated text boxes. The focus class just turns the border green whereas unfocused turns it red with the alert.

```
    <div class="addtextbox"><input type="submit" class="AddOption" value="Click To Add New Option"></div>



$(function() {
     $(".addtextbox").click(function() {
         $(".addtextbox").before("<input class='options'><br>");
     });
 });
```

Here is the code I used to add the textbox

Comment: Yes, it's almost certainly possible. Please show us what you've tried.

Comment: please provide the sample code to begin with

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  
  $(document).on("focus", ".options", function(){
    
    $(this).addClass("focused");
    $(this).removeClass("unfocused");
    
  });
  
  
  $(document).on("blur", ".options", function(){
    
    $(this).removeClass("focused");
    $(this).addClass("unfocused");
    
    if (!$(this).val()) {
       alert("Please ensure you have answered the question.");
    }
    
 });
  
  
  })
```

Comment: Hi, this has solved the problem. However, even if there is an input within the required field, it stays red instead of going back to having no colour.

Comment: Hi, thanks for all your help, I've managed to rearrange the code to make it work as it should :)

Comment: you can accept the answer if it really solved your problem

Answer (score 0):

You can possibly use the new jQuery plugins that rely on the HTML5 features such as `required`, for instance and delegate the validation event, making it work even in case of AJAX calls. In your AJAX response, try to generate inputs like:

```
<input type="text" required="required" pattern="{d}" />
```